# C# way to check if an MFC application is stuck

Tags: c#, mfc

I have a watchdog application written in C# that's keeping MFC processes running.
I'm doing it using the Exited event in System.Diagnostics.Process class:

```
Process _currentProcess = new Process();
_currentProcess.Exited += LaunchAgain;
```

where The LaunchAgain is a function that should start the process again.

The problem is that sometimes the MFC applications (written in C++ of course) get stuck with the familiar exception message: "MFC application has stopped working", but the process of this application is still alive.
So the watchdog doesn't know that the application is stuck, and it's staying stuck until manual restart.

Is there a way in C# to find if an MFC application is stuck while it's process is still alive?
So I can stop and start it automatically using my watchdog?

Comment: No there isnt a reliable way of doing this, if you have access to the source code of the MFC applications let them send a message to your watchdog. Or if you cant do that configure your watchdog to restart a app only after its been frozen for 10 seconds. Ofcourse this doesnt work on work heavy applications. This solution really depends on what you are doing and what you can implement, the correct way of doing it is as i mentioned to send messages between the applications because there is no way to know if the process is stuck or just working full load.

Comment: But windows "knows" the application is stuck, because it is sending the error message to the user. I think there is also an event log about it in the windows event viewer. So it's weird that in .NET there is no way of knowing it.

Comment: What does [`Process.Responding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.responding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) say?

Comment: I don't know because I can't simulate it. It just happens from time to time. But anyway, it's a boolean property and not an event like 'Exited'. So even if it will return the correct value, I will have to create another thread that will check endlessly for this value for all applications. and this is a bad solution from my POV.

Comment: Sure you can simulate it, just write a dummy MFC application that crashes and launch that app instead of the real application. BTW when you write "stuck" do you mean crashed ?

Comment: this is the problem, it doesn't crash. if it crashed than than the process is also killed and then it launches the 'Exited' event. it is just stuck with the MFC error message and the process is still alive. How can I make a dummy application that get stuck like this?

Comment: That's the point, the "MFC application has stopped working" message occurs when your app crashes. The process continues to exist until you dismiss the dialog showing the "MFC application has stopped working" message.

Comment: I understand the point but I need a way that my watchdog will discover that the application is in that status.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I just checked the responding state and it's 'true'! so anyway to check all processes for their responding state won't help me.